# What is the purpose of next('r') in the context of an RxJS Subject

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I'm still fairly new to the RxJS world (please pardon my semantics), but I've seen a few examples of code that creates a Subject to do some work, and then calls next(0), or next('r') on the subscription. It appears to re-run the stream, or rather fetch the next value from the stream.

However, when I tried using this to call an API for some data, it completely skips over the work it's supposed to do as defined in the stream (assuming it would "run" the stream again and get new data from the server), and instead my subscriber gets the 'r' or zero value back when I try to call next like that.

I get that making the subscription "starts execution of the stream", so to speak, but if I want to "re-run" it, I have to unsubscribe, and resubscribe each time.

Is it a convention of some kind to call next with a seemingly redundant value? Am I just using it in the wrong way, or is there a good use-case for calling next like that? I'm sure there's something fundamental that I'm missing, or my understanding of how this works is very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question, I definitely recommend you to read about *hot* and *cold* Observables.

- *cold* Observables execute each time someone `subscribe`s to it.

```
const a$ = of(5).pipe(tap(console.log))

a$.subscribe(); // the 'tap' will be executed here
a$.subscribe(); // and here, again.
```

- *hot* Observables do not care about subscriptions in terms of execution:

```
const a$ = of(5).pipe(
  tap(console.log),
  shareReplay(1)
);

a$.subscribe(); // the 'tap' will be executed here
a$.subscribe(); // but not here! console.logs only once
```

In your example you are using `Subject` that represents *cold* Observable.
You can try to use `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject` - both of them are *hot* but be aware that they behave differently.

IN you example you can modify your `Subject` like the following:

```
const mySubject = new Subject();

const myStream$ = mySubject.pipe(
  shareReplay(1)
);

myStream$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))

mySubject.next(1);
mySubject.next(2);
mySubject.next(3);
```